# Limite de linhas de código que podem ser postadas em uma pergunta/resposta

Tags: debate, perguntas, respostas

Existe algum limite máximo sugerido para a quantidade de linhas de código que podem ser postada em um único trecho?

Apesar do SOPT formatar muito bem trechos grandes, colocando barras de rolagem, existe algum limite aconselhável ou mandatório para a quantidade de linhas?

Comment: Acho que não, mas não convém colocar milhares de linhas, só excertos onde achamos que está o problema. No caso de precisar pode sempre usar qualquer coisa como o http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Ou até mesmo o http://pastebin.com :)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn na verdade o jsfiddle é um _simulador_ (não sei se é o termo correto, mas acho que deu pra entender, não deu?), enquanto o pastebin é apenas um _exibidor_. Aqui no SO não temos _simuladores_, por isso a necessidade do jsfiddle em algumas situações, entretanto temos como mostrar o código formatado no próprio corpo da pergunta, por isso a **não** necessidade do pastebin, rs..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mesmo que exista um limite técnico será um número tão alto que qualquer coisa próximo desse limite será uma pergunta ou resposta com padrões de qualidade longe dos desejados pela comunidade.

Leia o seguinte link:

[**Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

e tenha como habito instruir pessoas que não o conhecem a lerem também, como por exemplo o autor da pergunta que você acabou de responder:

[Declaração de variável “final” - Eclipse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15033/3117)

**Bônus:**

Gostaria de ressaltar algo que você não perguntou aqui, entretanto eu [comentei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15033/nullpointerexception-quando-criando-uma-view-no-android/15057#comment26815_15033) na pergunta acima mas não teve a devida atenção:

Responder é bom, mas mais do que isso queremos perguntas e respostas de qualidade que sejam de algum uso para futuros visitantes. Não estou dizendo que sua resposta é ruim, de forma alguma, entretanto para ela ser útil a pergunta também deve ser boa, e convenhamos, ela está horrível.

Não estou pedindo para você formatar todas as perguntas que você responder, mas nesse caso em específico eu dei a entender isso via o comentário que eu deixei lá pois o autor disponibilizou o código via um link e você com toda sua paciência de olhar um código de 450 linhas entendeu o problema e respondeu corretamente a pergunta.

Não é obrigação sua, mas se eu tivesse tido a paciência que você teve de entender o código eu iria mais além e editaria a pergunta para deixá-la entendível para qualquer um que ler o corpo da pergunta sem a necessidade de clicar em links.

Isso obviamente deveria ser o trabalho do autor da pergunta, portanto em casos assim sempre cabe uma mensagem para ele com links que o ajude a futuramente não depender da boa vontades dos outros membros da comunidade com o que é de trabalho dele.

Comment: concordo plenamente, eu quando vejo um link sem explicação nenhuma do problema, e bocados de código onde possa estar nem me dou ao trabalho de ir ver o link. A verdade é essa.

Comment: Estava na rua, no caminho para o serviço pensei muito naquela pergunta, e entrei agora para editá-la, mesmo porque ela não tem nada a ver com `final`. Aliás, estou editando ela agora ;)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn eu mesmo aprovei sua revisão entretanto tinha um link que eu não vi devido ao formato como as revisões aparecem na fila =/. Minha ideia era que na verdade fosse eliminado qualquer tipo de link, seja do comentário seja na pergunta, deixando apenas o essencial no corpo da pergunta. _Acredito_ (não tenho certeza pq não me aprofundei na questão) que apenas removendo o link externo resolve esse problema. A ideia é que no corpo da pergunta tenham todas as informações necessárias para perguntadores e visitantes.

Comment: Outro [exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15076/7210) que eu nem me dei ao trabalho de ir ver os links. Mas o @brasofilo foi generoso e fez o trabalho de casa do utilizador :)

Comment: Pois é, @Math... Mas arrumei... Ainda estou me acostumando com esse esquema de edições :) Refiz a edição, deixei o link, mas coloquei o método problemático ao qual minha resposta fez referência

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn sem problemas! o SOPT estará sempre receptivo para pessoas com boas intenções ;-) valeu pela compreensão

Comment: Precisamente. Um limite físico de linhas não resolve nenhum problema. Um bloco de 100 linhas **provavelmente** abrange coisas que não fazem parte do problema, porque é muito raro que um problema envolva 100 linhas. Um bloco grande não é "errado" por ser grande, mas sim porque provavelmente apresenta informações que não são relevantes.

Answer (score 3):

## 30.000 caracteres

Esse é o límite do que pode ser postado na plataforma Stack Exchange, seja texto ou código.
<sub>Vide [*Please notify me of the 30,000 character limit*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25066/185667)</sub>

E como [notado pelo fundador da rede](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13784/please-increase-the-maximum-allowed-length-for-answers/14142#14142):

> Se você "precisa" publicar mais de 30 mil caracteres, isso é sintomático de outros problemas.

Comment: Faz todo sentido! Gostaria de poder marcar mais de uma resposta como correta! ;)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn, a orientação do Math é perfeita, mas a resposta correta é a minha, jejeje, :P

Comment: @brasofilo a sua resposta é **teoricamente** correta, a minha é correta na **prática** :P

Comment: Taí, pronto! Vamos sugerir uma feature para "merge" de respostas! .... brincadeira ;)

Comment: pô, mas eu nem fiz ping pra você, @Math :)

Comment: @brasofilo eu não preciso de pings para ver o que está acontecendo :P (entretanto eu vou parar de ver por algumas horas a partir de agora pq tenho um compromisso e tenho que sair, rsrs..)